# special character breaking my json

Tags: json, utf-8

In an application I am creating, a user entered a name which I saved into the database. The name contained the letter e with an accent on it.

When my app retrieved this value and output it using json, my json was invalid.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem with using PHP's utf8_encode() function. But this strongly depends on your environment.

You should checked what encoding is in your database and what encoding your app is producing. Make sure to translate the encodings properly if they differ.

It would be helpful to further specify your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **URLEncoder.encode("YOUR STRING","UTF-8");**

Hop it will work for you.